# Woocommerce - blockUi style

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

When performing the Ajax request, blockUI adds style to the blocks of checkout form and cart – styles: “background: ‘#fff'”. My entire website is in black color and I never wanted the background of the blocks style to white. How can I remove this styles without modifying the woocommerce js files ?
It's part of woocommerce javascript which makes me a headache:

```
/**
     * Block a node visually for processing.
     *
     * @param {JQuery Object} $node
     */
    var block = function( $node ) {
        if ( ! is_blocked( $node ) ) {
            $node.addClass( 'processing' ).block( {
                message: null,
                overlayCSS: {
                    background: '#fff',
                    opacity: 0.6
                }
            } );
        }
    };
```

I tried to do this:

```
.processing {
  background: none!important;
}
```

But nothing came of it.

Answer (score 7):

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/overlay.html

```
div.blockOverlay {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this overrules the hard-coded CSS applied by the `.blockUI` javascript. Can you test this to confirm?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. +1.